# How to change desktop environment in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on VM and I can't change desktop environment. In previous versions you could switch between Unity and Gnome on login screen, but now this option have gone. [image]

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: btw if any answer below helped you, then be sure to accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick below the downvote button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you haven't installed it yet **:)**

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple DE's installed, you will see it.

Try Kubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

or lxde :

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Or gnome :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Please note, it downloads quite a few packages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even have GNOME installed? Open a terminal and run

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

After it's installed you should be able to login with GNOME.